# CentOS 7 Installation Error anaconda NoSuchGroup

Tags: python, linux, operating-system, centos, centos7

I'm trying to install CentOS 7 on virtual box but I faced this issue
after I Select the language it shows an error as the following

```
anaconda 21.48.22.93-1 exception report raceback (most recent call first): File H/usr/lib64/python2.7/site-packages/pyanaconda/packaging/yumpayload.py", line 1193, ir 
raise NoSuchGroup(groupid, required=required) File H/usr/lib64/python2.7/site-packages/pyanaconda/packaging/yumpayload.py", line 1306, ir self._selectYumGroup(°core")
```

this message is not the full message I used the OCR to extract the text from image because I cant copy the text from VBox you can view the next image to see

[image: image describes the error]

Comment: is there any one

Comment: This question belongs in https://superuser.com/

Stackoverflow is for programming questions.